# How to get binaries for libraries that have NuGet package, without using NuGet, listed on GitHub?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2008, nuget, moq, autofixture

Let me explain my circumstances first, then it will make sense. I'm writing an application which consists of a desktop application and some libraries which must be supported in the full framework and the **Compact Framework**.

I'm writing unit tests for my library that must be able to be compiled under CF 3.5. For these unit tests, I've grabbed useful tools, such as NUnit, FluentAssertions, Moq, AutoFixture, etc. However, since everyone has started moving these tools to GitHub they do not provide a direct download link to the binaries. They simply list the NuGet package install command.

However, I must use VS2008 to develop this library because later versions of VS do not support the Compact Framework v3.5 (stupid Microsoft). **VS2008 does not support NuGet**. Therefore, I've created a /lib folder in my project's directory to add 3rd party libraries such as these tools for unit tests. But, I'm having a hard time finding the .dll's for the tools.

Do I have to create a separate VS201X solution just to use the NuGet package manager to grab the binaries and then copy them to the VS2008 project? That's my current solution. When these tools were on code.google.com and others people always provided direct links to the binaries as well... but now it doesn't seem they do? Or am I missing an easy way to find them?

Here's some examples

[AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)
[Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)
[FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use NuGet with Visual Studio; you can also use the [nuget command line executable](https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference).

Example:

```
nuget install elmah
```

Once you have the packages down, the binaries are available unpacked in subdirectories under the `packages` folder.

Even if you have trouble unpacking the NuGet files, a `.nupkg` file is just a `.zip` file with another extension, so you can always rename it and unpack it like that.

However, all this may ultimately not help you for all libraries. For example, AutoFixture is only available for .NET 4 and above.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it had a separate command line outside of Visual Studio Extension. I'm now reading on how I can get 'nuget restore' to work without the extension. I was able to grab NUnit and other packages with it, but I'm not sure how to specify which version if there are multiple (2.0/4.0)

Comment: I guess the command line utility doesn't help me create a packages.config file, nor does it offer any sln or csproj support.